Desert War Film Question
I am trying to see again a desert war film where soldiers as using jeeps and come across a steep hill to go down. I remember the soldiers emptying one of the jeeps and then winching it down using the other jeeps. 
I have watched 'Sea of sand' thinking that must be the film but this scene does not appear.
Any information would de great. Thanks Glen

It's "Play Dirty" with Michael Caine. This is the scene you are referring to.

This sounds like a classic moment in the 1958 film Ice Cold in Alex
There is a point where the group tries to get their large army truck up a sand dune - with mixed results.
I have managed to find a video clip to see if this jogs your memory.



